# SwiftUI - open link from my website in the app

Tags: swiftui, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have one SwiftUI - iOS app running, and I need to open the link from email/whatsapp/etc in my app.
So lets say the link is like this (from my website):

https://www.mapplebook.com/welcome;id=123

I have tried the custom Scheme, which works fine, but for that i need to do something like: myScheme://www.mapplebook.com/etc....
Which is bad because Website and Android only understand things without the scheme.

The universal link looks like the best approach, I read a couple of things about Apple docs and some other questions, but could not make it work. :(

Is there any suggestion? Maybe some tutorial that I am missing.
Any help is much appreciated.

Editing the question as requested:

This is my info.plist - In this case I am using the custom scheme mapplebook

[image]

In SceneDelegate.swift, I have the followng:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
            return
        }
        
        if let range = url.absoluteString.range(of:"https//www.mapplebook.com/id=") {
            let sharedtoken = url.absoluteString[range.upperBound...]
            //with sharedtoken i can redirect internally and open the correct view - working okay
        }
}
```

But, as mentioned, that uses scheme mapplebook right?
Is it possible to have something like in android, where we say like:

```
android:host="mapplebook.com"
android:pathPattern="/something"
android:scheme="https" />
```

So it ask to open the https://mapplebook.com/something url in my app.

Thank you Koen for helping.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you share some of the code you tried (edit your question, don't put it in the comments). See also [ask].

Comment: I think you are looking for Universal Links: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: @Daniel, i see, is this the only way of doing this? I only ask this because of deploying the AASA in the server (azure), would be first time doing it, haha. Do you have a sample so i can take a look (besides from apple`s documentation)?

Comment: hey guys, i got it working, should i close this? tnks guys

Comment: @Luk2020so what was the answer for this question, whats the fix in SWIFTUI